# Does every graph have a tour?

Tags: graph-theory

> Does every graph have a tour?

Not every graph has a cycle, but can it be said that every graph, even disconnected, has a tour since there are really no restrictions on repeating edges or vertices so you can just backtrack to get back to the original vertex?

In my class a tour is a *walk* that starts and ends at the same vertex, and a walk is a sequence of consecutive edges which may have repeated vertices.

Comment: Definitions are your friends.  Perhaps your definition of "a tour" has no restrictions on repeating edges or vertices, but if it is to have any value as a definition, it probably does have *some* restrictions.  State your definition of "tour" so that Readers are better able to answer your Question ("does every graph have a tour?").

Comment: in my class a tour is a walk that starts and ends at the same vertex, and a walk is a sequence of consecutive edges which may have repeated vertices. I am assuming a walk can also have repeated edges because Eulerian tours are a subset of tours and those are defined as tours using each edge exactly once?

Comment: So the "null" tour that goes nowhere (starts and ends at the same vertex) would satisfy the definition?  Other authors use [definitions that differ significantly](http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Graph_Theory_-_basic_definitions#Paths.2C_tours.2C_walks) from yours, particularly in requiring no repeated edges and (in other contexts) a requirement on the vertices to be "visited".

Comment: yes, the notes were not clear on whether a walk can have repeated edges so I think I will go clarify.. I'm seeing now how my question is more just subject to definitions, but thanks for responding!

Answer (score 1):

Any connected graph has a tour, but how could a disconnected graph have one? Consider the graph consisting of $2$ vertices and no edges. There is no tour possible there.

Comment: I think in our class we define single vertices as each having a tour that starts and ends at themselves, so I guess with that definition each vertex would have its own tour? But yes I understand what you are saying!

Comment: In general, each connected component should have its own tour, but there is no way to get from one connected component to another one.

Comment: Ok this is what I just wanted to confirm, that by my definition of a tour every graph would have at least one. thanks!